# Concentration on a spell, does it include any of the components of casting it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, concentration

As a spell caster, when I am keeping a concentration effect up, does it require any of the casting components required to have cast it, such as verbal or somatic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Casting a spell is a different type of action to maintaining a spell, so no, there are none of the same requirements for components.

According to the magic rules for Concentration [duration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Duration).

> **Concentration**
>   The spell lasts as long as you concentrate on it. Concentrating to maintain a spell is a standard action that does not provoke attacks of opportunity. Anything that could break your concentration when casting a spell can also break your concentration while you’re maintaining one, causing the spell to end. See concentration.
>
> You can’t cast a spell while concentrating on another one. Some spells last for a short time after you cease concentrating.

Comment: Mostly I was thinking about the sound or action. Its clear that someone if focusing on a spell or cant hide if they are doing those things.

Comment: @Fering That would make invisibility useless...

Comment: @Adeptus Invisibility is not a concentration spell, its a duration

Comment: Very few spells actually use Concentration as a duration - mostly illusions.